# Is it possible to add an object structure under an array to the Eloquent model scheme?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I got a JSON object like this:

```
{
   "campaignDesignerAccountId":0,
   "remoteAccountId":0,
   "month":5,
   "usage":[
      {
         "service":"affectivity",
         "type":"renderVideo",
         "taskCount":"59",
         "totalDuration":"2597.845625400543"
      },
      {
         "service":"creatives",
         "type":"HTMLToPDF",
         "taskCount":"248",
         "totalDuration":"5412.990473032003"
      },
      {
         "service":"creatives",
         "type":"pdf",
         "taskCount":"229",
         "totalDuration":"27953.42511272434"
      },
      {
         "service":"displayads",
         "type":"html5",
         "taskCount":"8",
         "totalDuration":"199.255334138869"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to add the object under the `usage` array as an eloquent model schema.

For example:

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'campaignDesignerAccountId',
        'remoteAccountId',
        '[usage].service',
        '[usage].type',
        '[usage].taskCount',
        '[usage].totalDuration',
        'month',

    ];
```

Is it possible?

Currently, my eloquent model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PublishEngineMonthlyLogs extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'campaignDesignerAccountId',
        'remoteAccountId',
        'usage',
        'month'

    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'usage' => 'array'
    ];

    // Sorting parameters
    protected $allowedSorts = [
        'month'
    ];

    // Permission of filtering fields with texts
    protected $allowedFilters = [
        'month',
        'campaignDesignerAccountId'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators).

I updated my model class like this:

```
class PublishEngineMonthlyLogs extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'campaignDesignerAccountId',
        'remoteAccountId',
        'usage',
        'month',
        'year'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'usage' => 'array'
    ];

    // Sorting parameters
    protected $allowedSorts = [
        'month'
    ];

    // Permission of filtering fields with texts
    protected $allowedFilters = [
        'month',
        'campaignDesignerAccountId'
    ];

    public function setServiceAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['service'] = $value;
    }
    public function setTaskCountAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['taskCount'] = $value;
    }
    public function setTotalDurationAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['totalDuration'] = $value;
    }
    public function setTypeAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['type'] = $value;
    }

}
```

And assigned values like this:

```
$tableData= [];
$log= new PublishEngineMonthlyLogs;
$log->setAttribute('service', $dataRow['service']);
$log->setAttribute('type', $dataRow['type']);
$log->setAttribute('taskCount', $dataRow['taskCount']);
$log->setAttribute('totalDuration', $dataRow['totalDuration']);
array_push($tableData, $log);
```